# Servo motor rotation angle accuracy

Tags: servo

Let's say I want the motor rotate to 21.73 degree, will servo motor rotate to the desired degree accordingly? Or maybe the motor will rotate to 22 degree?

Comment: What sort of servo motor?

Comment: A RC micro servo motor.

Comment: Do you realize that there are literally thousands of different servo motors out there? Even the ones called "RC micro servo motor".

Comment: Clear case of zero research efforts. Nevertheless, even best digital hobby motors will not give you 0.01 degree accuracy. The best you could hope for is 0.1, and even that will not be temperature compensated.

Comment: Even the best RC servos have a deadzone setting that will preclude getting very accurate angular movements. However if you add a servo to more accurate gearbox you can get very good results: https://www.servocity.com/4-5-d485hw-400-servo-gearbox

Comment: @JackCreasey Naw, that wouldn't work. Have you read the description in full? They _mod_ the servo to use external pot, so basically you get exactly same precision only many times more torque. But the idea to use gearbox is right one. All you have to do then is use continuously rotating servo with encoder feedback on motor shaft. But that goes way beyond "RC micro servo motor".

Comment: @Maple. Naw, you are wrong, you can find gearboxes that use larger potentiometers in single turn configurations and some that use 10 turn potentiometers in multi-turn configurations. You get much higher resolution from the larger potentiometer components. You still of course have to deal with the deadzone settings which ultimately restricts the resolution. Clearly you haven't used any of them.

Comment: @JackCreasey I just love the "clearly" part... considering that I've been working on robotic assistive technology for past 10 years. Now, the gist of my comment was that for gearbox to work with required precision you need feedback from higher stage. Whether it is encoder or multi-turn potentiometer really does not matter. And BTW, the deadzone you so worrying about will also be erased by high gear ratio.

Comment: @Maple. Just as the deadzone for any RC servo without an external gearbox is a function of the internal potentiometer, the deadzone is a function derived from the external potentiometer resolution when an external gearbox is used. The deadzone is NOT reduced by the external gearbox/potentiometer to any extent, though potentially the higher resolution might allow better (smaller) calibration of the deadzone.

Comment: Let's say you have 5% deadzone as measured at the feedback point. If there is 1:10 ratio between the feedback stage and output gear then the deadzone is 0.5% when measured on the output. Just as precision of absolute positioning is increased by gearbox (your idea, not mine) so the deadzone is reduced on the output.

Comment: Oops sorry for the "zero research efforts" because I am still deciding which servo motor is used. I know there are many types of servo motor so I just ask if RC micro servo motor(any type) can rotate to some specific angle like I state in this post. I want to drive a solar panel to a very accurate angle and so I asked in this post. I am still figuring out which servo motor make it the best to drive the solar panel.

Answer (score 1):

Note: answering the post in comments, not the original XY-problem.

The average output of solar panel tracking the sun is about 20% more when compared to fixed (at optimal angle for your location) solar panel. Which means you don't need anywhere close to that precision. Even the worst hobby servos are precise enough. The selection criteria should be torque, not precision.

Having said that, you would most likely need a modded servo with high-ratio gearbox, or a special slow high-torque servo. The size of a solar panel the regular hobby servo can rotate is about enough to power that servo + control device.