# Very precise position motor recommendation

Tags: motor

I've been searching for a suitable motor for my solar panel and I need two motors to rotate to two angle that is solar azimuth and altitude. Since it involved a very precise angle calculation and so I hope I can find some motor that suit the project. My tracker is much more smaller compare to the others. Any motor that can recommend to me? I hope the price can be a lot cheaper.

Comment: "Very precise" isn't detailed enough. How precise do you demand? 1.8 degree/step? 1 degree/step? 0.1 degree/step?

Comment: Generally, with high gear ratios, you can achieve whatever precision you want.

Comment: With a solar panel, you don't need 'precise'. Anything that improves on 'leaving them fixed pointing in the same direction' improves on that. Or so I used to think, but my brother, who has an installation, has enlightened me. The cost of panels has fallen to around 30c/watt. If you have the area, it's cheaper, and far easier, to increase the output by installing more fixed panels, than to motorise a smaller number.

Comment: 30 cent per Watt only applies to used panels, as far as I know.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, since I wanted my panel to move to some specific angle so I hope it can go very precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since it involved a very precise angle calculation

Exactly what do you mean by "precise"? Keep in mind that the power from a solar cell is proportional to the cosine of the error angle - that is, maximum power is produced when the panel is perfectly perpendicular to the incoming light.

So how does error affect you? The cosine of 1 degree is 0.99984. A one degree alignment error will reduce panel power by .00016, or about .016%. As a matter of fact, an 8 degree error will only drop your power by 1%. Is this really cause for "a very precise angle calculation" ?

Another thing to consider is that, in principle, you need rather high torques available to deal with balance/wind loads. Since you don't need to do high-speed slewing (worst-case is 15 degrees per hour), the obvious approach is a rather small motor with a cheap, low-resolution encoder coupled to a rather high ratio gear box. Both torque and resolution are multiplied by the gear ratio. For that matter, unless you can justify angle precisions much less than 8 degrees, you can couple a rather coarse encoder to the panel rather than the motor, and not worry about losing track of rotation counts.

Comment: Absolutely agree with this, low resolution encoder on output stage of the gearbox is more than sufficient. Furthermore, since output stage has only one full rotation, the **absolute position** encoder can and should be used.

Comment: @Maple - Actually, since the trajectory will (approximately) repeat every day and will only be about 180 degrees, it's arguable that an absolute encoder is unnecessary. Instead, an incremental encoder can be used, at least for the E/W axis, as long as the home position is located in the daily path. For the N/S axis, I agree that absolute position is pretty much required. Even then, an incremental is acceptable if a reset cycle is performed every night. It would take more power and computation, but it's certainly doable.

Comment: So, why not use absolute rotary encoder for both and not bother with homing? With resolution 1-5 degrees you can find one for under $30. Actually, you can have resolution 10-20 degrees and very simple math for rough positioning, then use photo sensor to fine-tune.

Comment: @Maple - Shrug. That's a system design tradeoff. Incremental takes fewer IO lines. And before you say that a coarse absolute interface can't possibly require too many lines, consider that you do not know exactly what the poster is using. I brought up the incremental possibility because I don't know what the constraints are.

Comment: I was using "encoder" in rather broad sense. Hall effect, inductive and magnetoresistive rotary sensors have analog voltage, PWM and SPI outputs. 1 to 3 IO pins. But yes, you are right, OP did not provide enough details to go by.

Answer (score 1):

The "best" well, simplest and most effective for the cost that I saw was the use of two small solar panels (2" * 3") mounted at 90 degrees to each other with a jam jar filled with water acting as a lens.

The panels were wired in series but the two negatives connected together and the two positives drove a small motor which was geared to move the panels.

Whichever panel had the greatest output caused the motor to rotate, as this assembly was mounted with the support system it would find the "balance" point.

Small diagram:

[image]

If you check out the Homepower magasine - they have had a lot of different solutions to this with some very good or at least interesting ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you use direct drive, you need a BLDC with a high resolution encoder, no doubt about it. Although you should also admit that the panel precision is not like you are pointing to a star.

If you use gears, i would still go to BLDC, maybe even with encoder after the gear. But it's a very common practice to use 200 steps stepper motors.

Comment: "high resolution encoder" and "not like you are pointing to a star" kinda two opposite opinions in same paragraph, don't you think? Direct drive is a horrible idea, resulting in constant power drain. Not only you need a gearbox, but it should be self-locking too, like worm, for example.

Comment: Well.. High for this matter means higher than a stepper can reach, and accurate as encoder can be. I would bet that 10000 counts would be enough, but i am lazy for calculations. Besides, i don't know anything about the PV he uses (or any other).

Comment: While i agree about your bottom line (and this is what companies i worked with do), direct drive with a brake may appear much more cost effective, depending on the design. Obviously you don't want to hold the PV with the motor, but a mechanical brake would work just fine.

Comment: Technically, he IS pointing at a star, but the star is so damn close the angles don't matter as much...

Comment: Shit, they said its painted on the crystal sphere around earth...

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Wait a second, you said "high resolution encoder" while talking about BLDC. Now you saying "higher than a stepper can reach". Why on earth would you use encoder with _stepper_?

Comment: I would not. Well... My customers do that from time to time, but still. Anyway, it's stepper i see mostly after the worm gear. Not very efficientl, but cheap and simple. So i compare one way to it's opposite, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/382300/187920) regarding positioning precision.

Also, you have to use some of the generated power for your tracking system. If your panel is small it might be comparable or even bigger than the increase you get by tracking.

Finally, MPPT provides comparable efficiency increase while requiring much less power to operate. This would be your best option.

With all that said, if you still want to use solar tracking, then choose motors by their efficiency, not precision. You will get your precision with high gear ratio, as @LongPham commented earlier. Also some brushless motor controllers give you an access to encoder feedback as internal counter. You can use that for precise positioning (since it is read before the gearbox).

I also recommend taking a look at [Roboteq](https://www.roboteq.com/index.php/roboteq-products-and-services/brushless-dc-motor-controllers) controllers. Not only they support encoders and have built-in closed loop position mode, they also allow you to write your own script, so you might be able to implement your entire system without any additional parts, just motor controller and two brushless motors.